# How can I utilize a persisted URI with apps that don't support ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, uri, persistent-storage

My app allows a user to select media (images, video, audio) from whatever is their favorite app for navigating these documents. I then store the URI to that image (rather than downloading the entire image) into a db. On restart of the app, I need to utilize these URIs to pull thumbnails and for images, the complete image from the URIs in order to show them in the app.

I have read the various posts and the docs about using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT initially, granting the appropriate URI permissions, then using takePersistableUriPermission on the resolver.

All that works great. The problem is, there are a *lot* of apps in the world that manage media choosing that don't support ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, but that do support ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

What I want to do:

1. Provide a list of apps to allow the user to choose which one they have loaded that can find media for them they want to use in my app.
2. Use the selected app to choose the media.
3. Persist the URI of that media to a db so I can utilize it later.

This works perfectly when implementation of the initial intent for selecting the app to use to find the media is ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

I have no need to perform writes on the media - just open the selection (and utilize the resulting URIs chosen by the user), and store this URI for later usage.

How can I bridge the gap for needing persistent URI with apps that don't support a ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`:

Step #1: Make a copy of the data to some file that you control (open an `InputStream` on the content and copy the bytes to a `FileOutputStream`)

Step #2: Persist a `Uri` that points to your copy of the data

In other words, there is no guarantee that a `Uri` that you get back from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` will be useful in five minutes, let alone five hours, five days, five weeks, etc.

Alternatively, integrate a [file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created) and limit yourself to files visible to you on the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Mark - I'm familiar with the local file system solution. I was looking for a way I could support users browsing for files to create a "playlist" using sources from various cloud based repositories, then only downloading them when they actually wanted to view/play/listen to them. The notion that everything has to be local to your filesystem if you want to persist access across reboots seems odd. That's why I thought I was missing something...

Comment: I should say - "then only downloading them" meaning streaming to the playback device. The idea was to never store the actual file locally - only the URI. This way I could support devices with very minimal storage but for people that wanted to define significant playlists. Why duplicate the storage locally that is on spotify? Why not just use a dropbox account Id to search for images there, store the playlist by the definition of the URIs to the actual files?

Comment: @tfrysinger: You would need to look into dedicated SDKs for those services and see if they support some sort of media-search option that returns identifiers that you could persist that supports later playback of the media. The Android SDK does not have anything like that, with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` being the closest thing.

Comment: Yes, that's the route I started to go down, I implemented a custom document provider for dropbox as my first effort and that works, but it just seems like a lot of duplicate effort when there are so many great choosers out there and people have a particular one they already like to use. At one point I started to build in a "media library" feature to this app and then I thought - wait a minute, why are you doing this when there are so many good ones already available and likely already in use?